# Blank pages, no errors in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm a beginner. I'm  trying to  learn vue js . When I try to run any pages like /anything, it redirected to index.html page. I'm unable to find out the error.
Please help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Register.vue

```
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>

        <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
          <v-text-field
            label="Username"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>

     <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
        <v-text-field
                  label="Password"
            type="password"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>

      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
const routes = [];

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes });

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

index.js

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Router from "vue-router"
import Register from "@/components/Register"
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld";
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [

    {
      path: "/register",
      name: "Register",
      component: Register
    },

  ]
})
```

Comment: Also share the code for Register component.

Comment: I have included Register.vue as well. Please help me. @AlbertPinto

Comment: `v-model="register.username"` Where this `register` object is defined?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't defined but when I removed v-model ,it still doesnot work. @F.NiX

Comment: Are you trying to route within your spa or from extern into your spa?

Comment: Sorry ,I'm confused .I followd the multiple documentation @Estradiaz

Answer (score 0):

Your routes are empty in main.js:

```js
const routes = []; //<= here

const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes });
```

Assuming your router `index.js` is in a "src/router" folder, you don't need to instantiate a new VueRouter in your main.js, but just require your custom one like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router' //<= import your index.js as "router"

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

---

**Edit**:

If you want to keep the `history` mode, your need to define it in your customer router:

```js
import Vue from "vue"
import Router from "vue-router"
import Register from "@/components/Register"
import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld";
Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history, // <= here
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/register",
      name: "Register",
      component: Register
    },

  ]
})
```

Comment: Stil not working. When I removed const routes = [] const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes });, I got hash(#) in url. Please help me. @Sovalina